# Using auto as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto

I'm attempting to compile the following using GCC 4.7.1 with the `-std=c++11` flag set:

```
std::map<std::string, auto> myMap;
```

I'm attempting to create an object to contain a large amount of Json data of various types (int string, bool) as well as sub-structures (list, map) so I can't declare the type of the field value at compile time, so I thought I'd use the `auto` keyword for it.

However, when I try to compile it, I get the following

```
error: invalid use of ‘auto’
error: template argument 2 is invalid
error: template argument 4 is invalid
error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

Is there a special way to use `auto` as a template argument, or is it just not possible?

Comment: No. Check out Boost.Variant or Boost.Any.

Comment: `auto' keyword still doesn't allow to use C++ as dynamic language :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/libs/any/).

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> myMap;
```

`auto` is evaluated during compile time and cannot be used as a dynamic run-time type.

Comment: [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html) would be a much better suggestion for JSON, since there is a very limited number of types that JSON data structures can have.

Answer (score 3):

It is simply not possible. The type behind `auto` has to be deduced from something. The closest you can get to that is using `decltype` with some expression.

```
std::map<std::string, decltype(some expression)> myMap;
```

but `decltype` here resolves to a type, which you cannot just change at compile time.