# alternative to virtual typedef

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, typedef

I have an interface IEnumerable for template classes of List<>, Array<> and Dictionary<>. I was hoping to use typedef to get their templated types T.

I was hoping to do the following.

```
class IEnumerable
{
public:
    virtual typedef int TemplateType;
}
```

And then override in inherited member, but you cant make a virtual typedef. So is there any other way that i could get the type of an unknown template class (IEnumerable is not template)?

Comment: Retagged as C#, since to the best of my knowledge `virtual typedef` isn't a C++ feature.

Comment: @templatetypedef did u read the question?! i said that virtual typedef doesn't work and asked for opinions on alternatives. untag plz!

Comment: My apologies - since you were using type names like `IEnumerable`, `List`, `Array`, and `Dictionary`, I assumed this was C# code (since these types aren't built into C++).  Sorry about that!

Comment: @templatetypedef no probs. i can see how my names would confuse. Do you have any ideas as to the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not defining IEnumerable as a template class as well?

Comment: @thang i want to have it the same for all (like in c#, im a copy cat :P) and i also need it like this to allow me to make Reflection-like functionality.

Comment: @MrUniverse So is it a template or not? I'm sure you can do what you're asking, but we need to see where `template` goes and what the template parameter is.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Types will be resolved at compile time, so dynamic typing has no place in it.

Comment: So C# can do this not because they can do virtual typedef.  They use a base class of Object.  You can do the same.  Define a class of type Object.  Derive all of your collection element types from Object.  Then set up exactly the same pattern that C# does...

Comment: @thang yeah i was thinking of doing an Object class. but is List< T> where T : Object == List< Object>? would the compiler be able to convert the 2 implicitly?

Comment: @thang also how would i resolve the Object into a derived type without doing a dynamic cast of any possible type and then decltype that? is there a more reusable way of doing this?

Comment: actually you know, in c++11, you can just make the enumerator a template.  when you need to use it, i think you can use the auto keyword (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542873/c11-auto-semantics).  so when you access the enumerator, instead of having to do IEnumarator<T> u = collection.getEnumerator();  you can just do auto u = collection.getEnumerator();  I think that should work.

Comment: @thang auto (c++) == var (in c#)?

Comment: yeah implicit type. that's right.

Answer (score 6):

Well, here is what is discussed in the comments in case somebody with the same question later finds this.

Basically, you want to do something similar to C#'s List<>, Array<>, IEnumerable and IEnumerator.  However, you don't want to have to create a generic parent class Object because it may mean that you'll need to dynamic_cast every time.

Additionally, you don't want to make IEnumerable a template because you don't want to have to know the type when using the collection.

In fact, with C++11, you **can** make IEnumerable a template and not have to know the type by using the implicit type keyword **auto**, which is the C++11 equivalent of c#'s **var** keyword.

So to do this, what you can do is:

```
 template <class T>
 class IEnumerable { 
     public:
        virtual IEnumerator<T> getEnumerator() = 0; 
        // and more stuff
 }
```

then

```
  template <class T>
  class List : public IEnumerable<T> { 

  public:
         virtual IEnumerator<T> getEnumerator() { 
               return ListEnumerator<T>(this); 
         }
  }
```

and

```
  template <class T>
  class ListEnumerator : public IEnumerator<T> { 
  public:
        T getNext();   // or something to this effect
        // and more stuff
  }
```

Finally, when it comes to using it, you can do:

```
  List<int> myList;


  auto i = myList.getEnumerator();
  int z = i.getNext()+1;
```

Comment: +1 a very good summing up. now even i understand it all better :P

Comment: also can i do ListEnumerator<auto> = myList.getEnumerator(); ?

Comment: and can i typedef auto (aka typedef ListEnumerator<auto> ListEnum;)

Comment: your joking?! List<auto> works! naaaa i dont believe it. its too awesome even for c++ :P ill check it out tomorrow

Comment: actually, I don't know.  I thought you tried it!  turns out it doesn't work;  however, boost::any works the same way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176972/using-auto-as-a-template-parameter

Comment: you know, it seems strange to me that you can't do something with auto in the template argument.  seems like you should be able to resolve it at compile time...

Comment: yeah but as implied, i didnt expect it to be that smart anyway :( ah well. thanks for your time and comments, i learnt a lot :)