# alternative to virtual typedef without templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, iterator

*Edited Shorter Question:
When using a pointer to an abstract class, how can I call methods of the actual type of the object it points to?*

I have an abstract `BaseTree` class with a public

```
virtual BaseTree const& operator[](NodeIndex const& poss) const = 0;
```

where `NodeIndex` is in practice `std::vector<unsigned int>`. I have also a `TreeBasicIterator` class which includes

```
public:
    /// Access the tree to which m_tree points
    BaseTree& operator*() const
    {
        //checking...
        return (*m_tree)[*this];
    }

private:
    /// the tree the current iterator refers to
    BaseTree* m_tree=nullptr;
```

*Problem* (I think it is the crux of my initial question below):

How can I use the methods of the class corresponding to the actual type of *m_tree? For now, when dereferencing my iterator, I can only use methods of the abstract class `BaseTree`.

I would like to avoid making `TreeBasicIterator` a template (see the initial question below).

*Initial Question*

As many (relatively new?) users of C++, I would like to write

```
virtual typedef something my_virtual_type;
```

inside classes definitions. Unfortunately it is not possible...

The most popular alternative seems to be templates, as for instance in  [alternative to virtual typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741442/alternative-to-virtual-typedef) which provides a nice sum up.

However I am not sure it covers everything a virtual typedef would. I present below a problem, for which I would like to have virtual typedefs. I have a (temporary?) working solution using overloading and not templates.

I want to create a fancy tree structure, including iterators.

1) I define a `NodeIndex` type, ancestor of my future iterators. (`NodeIndex` is in my case `std::vector<unsigned int>`, but it doesn't matter.)

2) I define an abstract `BaseTree` class, used in my iterators bellow. The class includes in particular virtual methods which returns `NodeIndex` indexes to move in the tree (e.g. `NodeIndex begin()`), and `operator[](NodeIndex const&)`.

3) I define a `TreeBasicIterator` class, inheriting from `NodeIndex`, which for coherence purpose includes a const reference to a `BaseTree`, and implements various iterators methods (making use of the virtual methods provided by `BaseTree`).

(I have actually two classes: `TreeBasicIterator`, and `Const_TreeBasicIterator` with a const reference to a `const BaseTree`; I use preprocessor macros to mimic a template based on const-ness, but this is another problem.)

4) I have defined a `TreeNode<T>` template class (`T` is the node content), inheriting from `BaseTree`. For now its `begin()` method returns a `NodeIndex`, and its `operator[]` takes a `NodeIndex` as argument, and everything works fine.

5) However I want to include my `TreeBasicIterator` in my `TreeNode` class. I would like to include a

```
virtual typedef NodeIndex Iterator;
```

in my `BaseTree` class, and modify the virtual `begin()` method signature to `Iterator begin()`.
Then `TreeNode` would include a

```
virtual typedef TreeBasicIterator Iterator;
```

its `begin()` method signature would be `Iterator begin()`, 
and everything would be hopefully fine :)

6) I do not wish to use templates on `TreeBasicIterator`: it is now compiled once for all.

Making `BaseTree` a template would make `TreeBasicIterator` a template, and so loose a part of the benefits of the abstraction in `BaseTree`.

Instanciating `BaseTree` with `NodeIndex` as `Iterator` type would be superfluous: in practice nobody would inherit from that particular instance.

7) Prospective:

I will use trees with a fixed or rarely modified structure, but more frequently modified node contents, and even much more frequently read accesses. To optimize access, I intend to further derive from `TreeNode` a `TreeVector` class, which will include a sorted exhaustive `std::vector` of `NodeIndex` (or `BasicTreeIterator`?) indexes. The `Iterator` virtual type in `TreeVector` would be std::iterator.

8) Current (temporary?) partially working solution:

`TreeNode` defines (via a usual `typedef`) an `Iterator` type (my `TreeBasicIterator` class). It does not override an `Iterator` type from `BaseTree`, but it could.

`BaseTree` has a `NodeIndex begin() const` method, which is both un-hidden, and overloaded in `TreeNode` by a `Iterator begin() const` method. It is not overridden.

Similarly, I have a `NodeIndex next_index(NodeIndex) const` in `BaseTree`, which is both un-hidden, and overloaded in `TreeNode` by a `Iterator next_index(Iterator) const` method.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. End of story.

Comment: @Sam: I know that. I'm looking for a potentially more efficient alternative that the solution I have in my point 8)

Comment: Since I am new, maybe comments to explain down votes would help me

Answer (score 0):

So, It does not seem to interest anyone... Anyway, here my working solution: mixing template and non template classes.

`TreeBasicIterator` remains a non-template class as explained in the question.

`dynamic_cast` is the tool to call tree class-specific methods on its `BaseTree` pointer. However it is not reasonnable to have to use it each time an iterator is dereferenced in the code.

I derive a template `TreeIterator` class:

```
template<class MyTree> class TreeIterator: public TreeBasicIterator
```

whose methods use `dynamic_cast`, for instance:

```
TreeIterator(BaseTree & tree): TreeBasicIterator(tree) {check_type();};

MyTree& operator*() const
{
    return dynamic_cast<MyTree &>(TreeBasicIterator::operator*());
}

void check_type()
{
    try
    {
        // uses the built-in checkings of dynamic_cast
        if(m_tree!=nullptr) dynamic_cast<MyTree &>(*m_tree);
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        m_tree=nullptr; // invalidates the iterator
        throw e;
    }
}
```

And the once-for-all compiled methods of `TreeBasicIterator` are called when what is done is independent of the real tree class used.